# TMP File Not Found Exception when deploying a DACPAC using 'SQL Server Database Deploy' Task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dacpac

I'm trying to deploy my Database Project (DACPAC File) using DevOps Pipeline.

But I'm getting the following error, and I did many trials to fix it with 
no hope!

That does not mean that it's always failing! Only 50% of my trials are succeeded!

```
2018-12-12T14:35:30.4214926Z ##[section]Starting: MyProject1 SPs
   2018-12-12T14:35:30.4245271Z ==============================================================================
   2018-12-12T14:35:30.4245604Z Task         : SQL Server Database Deploy
   2018-12-12T14:35:30.4246267Z Description  : Deploy to SQL Server Database using DACPAC or SQL scripts
   2018-12-12T14:35:30.4246507Z Version      : 0.3.13
   2018-12-12T14:35:30.4246714Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
   2018-12-12T14:35:30.4246978Z Help         : [More Information](https://aka.ms/sqldacpacmachinegroupreadme)
   2018-12-12T14:35:30.4247240Z ==============================================================================
   2018-12-12T14:36:23.4445256Z ##[error]Publishing to database 'XXXX_Db' on server 'DbServer1'. 
   Initializing deployment (Start) 
   Initializing deployment (Failed) 
   An unexpected failure occurred: Could not find file 'C:\Users\myuser1\AppData\Local\Temp\bfa36123-63a0-40be-be2b-0d953d8427e9.2.tmp'.. 
   System.Management.Automation.RemoteException Unhandled Exception:   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\myuser1\AppData\Local\Temp\bfa36123-63a0-40be-be2b-0d953d8427e9.2.tmp'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.CachedString.GetFileStream()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.CachedString.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 substringLength)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.ScriptCache.GetScript(String cacheIdentifier, Int32 startOffset, Int32 length)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlScriptProperty.get_Script()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlModelComparer.ArePropertiesEqual(IModelElement source, IModelElement target, ModelPropertyClass propertyClass, ModelComparerConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.Sql120ModelComparer.ArePropertiesEqual(IModelElement source, IModelElement target, ModelPropertyClass propertyClass, ModelComparerConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.ModelComparer.CompareProperties(IModelElement sourceElement, IModelElement targetElement, ModelComparerConfiguration configuration, ModelComparisonChangeDefinition changes)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.ModelComparer.CompareElementsWithoutCompareName(IModelElement sourceElement, IModelElement targetElement, ModelComparerConfiguration configuration, Boolean parentExplicitlyIncluded, Boolean compareElementOnly, ModelComparisonResult result, ModelComparisonChangeDefinition changes)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.ModelComparer.CompareElementsWithSameType(IModelElement sourceElement, IModelElement targetElement, ModelComparerConfiguration configuration, ModelComparisonResult result, Boolean ignoreComparingName, Boolean parentExplicitlyIncluded, Boolean compareElementOnly, Boolean compareFromRootElement, ModelComparisonChangeDefinition& changes)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.ModelComparer.CompareChildren(IModelElement sourceElement, IModelElement targetElement, ModelComparerConfiguration configuration, Boolean parentExplicitlyIncluded, Boolean compareParentElementOnly, ModelComparisonResult result, ModelComparisonChangeDefinition changes, Boolean isComposing)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.ModelComparer.CompareElementsWithoutCompareName(IModelElement sourceElement, IModelElement targetElement, ModelComparerConfiguration configuration, Boolean parentExplicitlyIncluded, Boolean compareElementOnly, ModelComparisonResult result, ModelComparisonChangeDefinition changes)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.ModelComparer.CompareElementsWithSameType(IModelElement sourceElement, IModelElement targetElement, ModelComparerConfiguration configuration, ModelComparisonResult result, Boolean ignoreComparingName, Boolean parentExplicitlyIncluded, Boolean compareElementOnly, Boolean compareFromRootElement, ModelComparisonChangeDefinition& changes)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.ModelComparer.CompareChildren(IModelElement sourceElement, IModelElement targetElement, ModelComparerConfiguration configuration, Boolean parentExplicitlyIncluded, Boolean compareParentElementOnly, ModelComparisonResult result, ModelComparisonChangeDefinition changes, Boolean isComposing)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.ModelComparer.CompareElementsWithoutCompareName(IModelElement sourceElement, IModelElement targetElement, ModelComparerConfiguration configuration, Boolean parentExplicitlyIncluded, Boolean compareElementOnly, ModelComparisonResult result, ModelComparisonChangeDefinition changes)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.ModelComparer .CompareElementsWithSameType(IModelElement sourceElement, IModelElement targetElement, ModelComparerConfiguration configuration, ModelComparisonResult result, Boolean ignoreComparingName, Boolean parentExplicitlyIncluded, Boolean compareElementOnly, Boolean compareFromRootElement, ModelComparisonChangeDefinition& changes)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.ModelComparer.CompareAllElementsForOneType(ModelElementClass type, ModelComparerConfiguration configuration, ModelComparisonResult result, Boolean compareOrphanedElements)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.ModelComparer.CompareStore(ModelStore source, ModelStore target, ModelComparerConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.CompareModels(SqlSchemaModel source, SqlSchemaModel target, SqlDeploymentOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.InitializePlanGeneratator()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.CreateController(Action`1 msgHandler)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.CreateController(SqlDeployment deploymentEngine, ErrorManager errorManager)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.<>c__DisplayClass3.<>c__DisplayClass5.<CreatePlanInitializationOperation>b__1()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Dac.OperationLogger.Capture(Action action)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.<>c__DisplayClass3.<CreatePlanInitializationOperation>b__0(Object operation, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Operation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.ReportMessageOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.Execute(IOperation operation, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.InternalDeploy(IPackageSource packageSource, Boolean isDacpac, String targetDatabaseName, DacDeployOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, Action`3 reportPlanOperation, Boolean executePlan)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.Deploy(DacPackage package, String targetDatabaseName, Boolean upgradeExisting, DacDeployOptions options, Nullable`1 cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.DacServiceUtil.<>c__DisplayClassd.<DoDeployAction>b__2(DacServices service)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.DacServiceUtil.ExecuteDeployOperation(CommandLineArguments cmdlineArgs, String connectionString, String filePath, String modelFilePath, MessageWrapper messageWrapper, Boolean sourceIsPackage, Boolean targetIsPackage, Boolean authType, String tenantId, String customAuthArgs, Func`1 generateScriptFromPackage, Func`2 generateScriptFromDatabase)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.DacServiceUtil.DoDeployAction(DeployArguments deployArgs, Action`1 writeError, Action`2 writeMessage, Action`1 writeWarning, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CommandLineArguments cmdlineArgs)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.DoDeployActions(CommandLineArguments parsedArgs)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.PerformAction(CommandLineArguments parsedArgs)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.Main(String[] args)

   2018-12-12T14:36:23.4766288Z ##[section]Finishing: MyProject1 SPs
```

Comment: Did you try to build this project in you machine? It's all right?

Comment: @mcamara .. yes sure I can publish the sql project from my machine.

Comment: Are you trying to do deploy your database from Build Pipeline or Release Pipeline?

Comment: @mcamara release pipeline.

Comment: Did you copied dacpac from build pipeline to artifact environment, using Copy File task?

Comment: Yep. The last step in build pipeline is 'Publish Build Artifacts' task. And i'm dropping it in a shared path \\ArtifactServerName\TfsProjectReleases\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildNumber)

Comment: I think you need to use copy file before Publish Build Artifacts, like this: https://imagebin.ca/v/4QIfTY0U4B4t

Comment: @mcamara, ok i got your point. Yes sure i'm doing that. check the build pipeline  https://ibb.co/3rZZbC2 also i just checked the file https://ibb.co/NgRW8Gx

Comment: Can  you post an image from your build pipeline definition?

Comment: @mcamara thank your for replying ... Here is the build deinfation https://ibb.co/vdwbGSF it's large a little bit :) 
However, I believe that I do not have a problem with build definition because i'm sure that I can see dacpac file in Release Server (it's downloaded in the downloading artifact step) ... Maybe something missing in Release server? Or configuration? What do you think?